# PostGIS version 3.0x on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Any way of updating the PostGIS version on a Postgres instance deployed by heroku?

```
=> select PostGIS_Lib_Version();
 postgis_lib_version 
---------------------
 2.5.4
(1 row)
```

Need the update files:

```
=> ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO "3.0.0";

ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.5.4" to version "3.0.0"
```

Any way of adding the update files to the instance?